# How to use replication and sharding together in Redis?

Tags: redis

I am using Redis . I want to know that-
How can we use both sharding and replication together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sharding you can either roll your own or checkout the latest master in github. The latest master has had sharding for more than a year now, although it's unstable and in development, but I've used it in production and it worked great. For sharding and replication both, I guess it comes down to having Redis shards in a cluster (I would really go for the alpha code, if you're not doing anything extremely serious), then just launch some other servers configured as slaves of members of the cluster. I'm not sure if Sentinel is prepared to promote the slaves to members of the cluster though...

I would really recommend you check [this article](https://moot.it/blog/technology/redis-as-primary-datastore-wtf.html). It's about turning a huge server (244GB of RAM) into a Redis cluster with replication and saving snapshots to Amazon S3, for backing up. If it does not contain the solution to your problem it will definitely help in designing some architecture.

Comment: I am doing sharding using twemproxy . And I know how to make master slave. But I want to know that how can we use them together with good performance.

Comment: thanks . Now i am using sentinel . It is monitoring my masters perfectly

Answer (score 0):

With redis, you have to do sharding all on your own!